# JPA NamedStoredProcedure return simple objects

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, stored-procedures, eclipselink

I've stored a procedure on DB Postgres that returns some colums.

```
List<Object[]> listrecord = this.em.createNamedStoredProcedureQuery("ContrVen.services")
          .setParameter("dataval", datavalidita).getResultList();
```

The procedure returns a list of Object[];

Does exist a way to cast Object[] to MyRow object?

I'am using **EclipseLink 2.6.0** as persistence provider. MyRow is **not an entity** so I can't use `resultClasses = MyRow.classes` because eclipselink throws an exception (MyRow is not a known entity type).

Comment: Where in the JPA spec does it say that a "resultClass" has to be an Entity? It doesn't

Comment: there isn't but if I use it an exception is throw : MyRow is not a known entity class

Comment: which JPA provider comes out with that exception?

Comment: eclipselink, I add it to question ;)

Comment: If this isn't an entity, you need to define a SqlResultSetMapping and specify a ConstructorResult that tells the provider which fields go into the POJO constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example from 3.10.16.2.2 of the JPA 2.1 specification:

```
@SqlResultSetMapping(name="CustomerDetailsResult",
    classes={
        @ConstructorResult(targetClass=com.acme.CustomerDetails.class,
            columns={
                @ColumnResult(name="id"),
                @ColumnResult(name="name"),
                @ColumnResult(name="orderCount"),
                @ColumnResult(name="avgOrder", type=Double.class)})
})
```

You would then use it in your query

```
List<CustomerDetails> listrecord = this.em.createNamedStoredProcedureQuery("ContrVen.services", "CustomerDetailsResult")
          .setParameter("dataval", datavalidita).getResultList();
```

Comment: Thank you! It work! But I have not found createNamedStoredProcedureQuery(String,String), only createNamedStoredProcedureQuery(String), so I added the result mapping in the definition of the named stored procedure: 
`@NamedStoredProcedureQuery( name = "ContrattoVen.servizilistino", procedureName = "servizilistino", resultSetMappings = {"ServiziAggiuntiviMapping"},
        parameters = {
            @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, type = Date.class, name = "dataval")
        }
    )`